# Cannot read property length of undefined error happens only in server

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using MVC and Kendo Grid. I am facing an issue where we have common functions for all our master tables and stores the result set to a cache based on dealersystemId.
There are different dealersystemId, so data will be stored in the cache for each of dealersystemId.
So whenever a call required for a master table, it always uses cache rather than going to call master tables, if there is no data in the cache for a particular master table only then it hit the database, otherwise reads from the cache.
We have a screen it shows all data from the cache, and the user will be able to delete stored cache for each dealersystemid. So here when a user clicks on 'clearcache' button for a dealersystemId, a Jquery ajax will happen and it deletes data from the cache for a dealersystemid, and remaining data in the cache will be shown in the Kendo grid.
Function which clears cache data code as mentioned below,

```or-tag-here
public List<SystemPreferenceModel> ClearAllSysPreference(string dealerSystemID,bool selfClear = true)
    {
        try
        {
            List<SystemPreferenceModel> systemPreferenceModel = null;
            List<mtSystemPreference> appSystemPrefModel = null;
            appSystemPrefModel = (List<mtSystemPreference>)CachingProvider.Instance.GetItem("GetAllSysPreference2");
            if (appSystemPrefModel != null)
            {
                systemPreferenceModel = new List<SystemPreferenceModel>();
                IGenericDataRepository<mtSystemPreference> appSysPrefRepository = new GenericDataRepository<mtSystemPreference>(UserModelSession);
                appSystemPrefModel.RemoveAll(x => x.dealerSystemId == Convert.ToInt64(dealerSystemID));
                systemPreferenceModel = GetSystemPreferenceData(appSystemPrefModel);
                CachingProvider.Instance.AddItem("GetAllSysPreference2", appSystemPrefModel, string.Empty);
            }
            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            string server1 = appSettings["Server1"];
            string server2 = appSettings["Server2"];
            if (selfClear == true && !server1.Contains("localhost"))
            {
                string Server1IPAddress = server1.Split(':')[1].Substring(2);

                if (UserModelSession.ServerIPAddress != Server1IPAddress)
                {
                    server2 = server1;
                }
                NetTcpBinding tcpb;
                string PropagationEndPoint = "";
                PropagationEndPoint = server2 + "/CommonComponent";
                tcpb = new NetTcpBinding();
                tcpb.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
                EndpointAddress ep = null;
                ep = new EndpointAddress(PropagationEndPoint);

                using (ChannelFactory<ICommonComponent> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICommonComponent>(tcpb))
                {
                    ICommonComponent proxy = factory.CreateChannel(ep);

                    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
                    {
                        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("usermodel", "utp_ns", ""));
                        proxy.ClearAllSysPreference(dealerSystemID, false);
                    }

                }
            }

            return systemPreferenceModel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            bool rethrow = BusinessLogicExceptionHandler.HandleExcetion(ref ex);
            if (rethrow)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**It works fine in local. View as follows**

```html
<div id="dvSysPref">
                        <div style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:5px;">
                            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.mtSystemPreferenceViewModel)
        .Name("SystemPreferenceGrid")
        .Selectable()
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(model => model.entityType).Width("50px").Title("EntityType");
            columns.Bound(model => model.entityId).Width("150px").Title("EntityID");
            columns.Bound(model => model.dealerSystemId).Width("150px").Title("Dealer SystemID");
            columns.Bound(model => model.name).Width("150px").Title("name");
            columns.Bound(model => model.valInt).Width("50px").Title("ValInt");
            columns.Bound(model => model.valString).Width("150px").Title("ValString");
            columns.Bound(model => model.createdDate).Width("150px").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(createdDate, \"MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt\") #").Title("createdDate");
            columns.Bound(model => model.lastUpdatedDate).Width("150px").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(lastUpdatedDate, \"MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt\") #").Title("LastUpdatedDate");
            columns.Bound(model => model.isActive).Width("150px").Title("IsActive");
            columns.Bound(model => model.valBin).Width("100px").Title("ValBin");

        })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; min-height: 100px; table-layout: fixed;" })
          .Pageable(pg =>
                                  pg.Refresh(true)
                                     .PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 30, 50, 100, 200 })
                                     .Enabled(true)
                                     .PreviousNext(true)
                                     .Numeric(false)
                                     .Input(true)
                                     .Messages(m => m.Page("Page ")
                                                   .Of(" of {0}")
                                                   )

                         )
         .Navigatable()
         .Filterable()
         .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(400))
         .Sortable(sort => sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
         .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
         .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
         .NoRecords("No Records Found")
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.mtSystemPreferenceId);
                model.Field(p => p.entityType);
                model.Field(p => p.entityId);
                model.Field(p => p.name);
                model.Field(p => p.valInt);
                model.Field(p => p.valString);
                model.Field(p => p.createdDate);
                model.Field(p => p.createdBy);
                model.Field(p => p.lastUpdatedDate);
                model.Field(p => p.lastUpdatedBy);
                model.Field(p => p.dealerSystemId);
                model.Field(p => p.isActive);
                model.Field(p => p.valBin);
            }
            )
            .Read(read => read.Action("ReadSystemPreferenceListGrid", "ClearCache"))
            )
                            )
                        </div>
                        <div style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:5px;">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("DealerSystemSysPreferenceList")
    .BindTo(Model.SystemPreferenceDealerSystemViewModelList)
    .DataTextField("DealerSystemID")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("LoadSystemSysPreferenceListDropdown", "ClearCache");
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
     })
     .Events(e =>
            {
                e.DataBound("onSystemPreferenceDataBound");
            })
    .OptionLabel("Select Dealer System ID")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30%" })
                            )
                            <input type="button" id="btnSysPreferenceClearCache" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" title="Search" value="Clear Cache" />
                            <div>
                                <span id="dvSystemPreferenceListvalidMesg" class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg field-validation-error" role="alert" style="display:none;text-align:left;position:absolute;margin:0px!important;padding:1px!important;bottom: 400px;"><span class="k-icon k-warning"> </span> Please select a dealer system ID</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JQuery ajax code,

```js
function onSystemPreferenceDataBound(e) {
          $("#btnSysPreferenceClearCache").click(function () {
                    var dealerSystemID = $("#DealerSystemSysPreferenceList").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
                    if (dealerSystemID != "Select Dealer System ID") {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: '/ClearCache/ClearSystemPreferenceListCache',
                            data: { dealerSystemID: dealerSystemID },
                            pageSize: 20,
                            cache: false,
                            pageable: true,
                            success: function (src) {
                                alert('Systempreference Cache has been cleared for dealerSystemId '+dealerSystemID);
                                var dealerDropdown = [];
                                var dropdownList = [];
                                if (src.Data.length > 0) {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < src.Data.length; i++) {
                                        dropdownList.push({ text: src.Data[i].dealerSystemId, value: i });
                                    }
                                    //Removes duplicates from dropdown
                                    dealerDropdown = dropdownList.reduce(function (item, e1) {
                                        var matches = item.filter(function (e2)
                                        { return e1.text == e2.text });
                                        if (matches.length == 0) {
                                            item.push(e1);
                                        }
                                        return item;
                                    }, []);
                                    dealerDropdown.unshift({ text: "Select Dealer System ID", value: "0" });
                                }
                                else {
                                    dealerDropdown = [
                                        { text: "Select Dealer System ID", value: "0" },
                                    ];
                                }
                                var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                    data: src,
                                pageSize: 20,
                                    schema: {
                                        type: "json",
                                        data: "Data",
                                        total: "Total",

                                        model: {
                                            fields: {
                                                mtSystemPreferenceId: { type: "number" },
                                                entityType: { type: "number" },
                                                name: { type: "string" },
                                                dealerSystemId: { type: "number" },
                                                valInt: { type: "number" },
                                                valString: { type: "string" },
                                                createdDate: { type: "date" },
                                                createdBy: { type: "number" },
                                                lastUpdatedDate: { type: "date" },
                                                lastUpdatedBy: { type: "number" },
                                                isActive: { type: "bool" },
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                $('#SystemPreferenceGrid').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(dataSource);
                                $("#DealerSystemSysPreferenceList").kendoDropDownList({
                                    dataTextField: "text",
                                    dataValueField: "value",
                                    dataSource: dealerDropdown
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Please select a DealerSystemID');
                    }
                });
    }
```

my Controller code as follows,

```or-tag-here
public ActionResult ClearUsersListCache(string dealerSystemID)
    {
        SupportViewModel supportVM = new SupportViewModel();
        UsersViewModel usersListModel = new UsersViewModel();
        supportVM.userViewModelList = new List<UsersViewModel>();
        List<UserModel> UserListInfoModel = new List<UserModel>();
        List<DealerSystemViewModel> dealerSystemViewmodel = new List<DealerSystemViewModel>();
        supportVM.UsersDealerSystemViewModelList = new List<DealerSystemViewModel>();
        DTNAUserModel dtnaUserModel = (DTNAUserModel)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DTNAConnectUser"];
        DTNAUserModel systemUserLoginModel = new DTNAUserModel();

        try
        {
            using (BusinessLayerServiceFactory<ICommonComponent> commonComponentServiceFactory = new BusinessLayerServiceFactory<ICommonComponent>())
            {
                    ICommonComponent commonComponent = commonComponentServiceFactory.Instantiate();
                    using (OperationContextScope ocs = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)commonComponent))
                    {
                        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader(commonComponentServiceFactory.UserModelName, commonComponentServiceFactory.UserModelNameSpace, commonComponentServiceFactory.SerializedUserModel));
                        UserListInfoModel = commonComponent.ClearAllUsers(dealerSystemID);
                    }
            }
            if (UserListInfoModel != null)
            {
                foreach (var user in UserListInfoModel)
                {
                    UsersViewModel userViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
                    {
                        {
                            userViewModel.Gid = user.Gid;
                            userViewModel.mtUserId = user.mtUserId;
                            userViewModel.BranchId = user.BranchId;
                            userViewModel.DeptId = user.DeptId;
                            userViewModel.UserId = user.UserId;
                            userViewModel.DmsUserId = user.DmsUserId;
                            userViewModel.DealerSystemId = user.DealerSystemId;
                            userViewModel.Description = user.Description;
                            userViewModel.Email = user.Email;
                            userViewModel.Role = user.Role;
                            userViewModel.isActive = user.isActive;
                            userViewModel.Password = user.Password;
                            userViewModel.RecActive = user.RecActive;
                            userViewModel.Facility = user.Facility;
                        }
                        supportVM.userViewModelList.Add(userViewModel);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < UserListInfoModel.Count; i++)
                {
                    supportVM.UsersDealerSystemViewModelList.Add(new DealerSystemViewModel { DealerSystemID = UserListInfoModel[i].DealerSystemId.ToString(), ID = Convert.ToInt64(i + 1) });
                }

                //This removes duplicates
                supportVM.UsersDealerSystemViewModelList = supportVM.UsersDealerSystemViewModelList.GroupBy(i => i.DealerSystemID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
            }

            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = supportVM.userViewModelList.OrderByDescending(x => x.mtUserId), // Process data (paging and sorting applied)
                Total = supportVM.userViewModelList.Count  // Total number of records
            };
            var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bool rethrow = UserInterfaceExceptionHandler.HandleException(ref ex);
            if (rethrow)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, when it got deployed we are able to see one javascript error 'Can not read property length of undefined'. This error happens only in the server not in local. When I debugged I could see that in Jquery success function controller returns view instead data which causes this error. Hence in the data return in success function is undefined, hence in 'src.Data.length' length property comes as undefined.
[SystemPreferenceGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw1Y2.png)
Please note I have attached a screenshot for the same error happens for one more grid we have.
But we could not reproduce this issue in local. So could anyone help me in fixing this issue?